# TreeMap - Synchronization Documentation Explanation

Tags: java, javadoc

TreeMap javadoc has the below part and i could not understand the last line of the below part. Does it means to create a lock and move the map modification logic into a synchronized block or something else all together. Will only the structural modification requires synchronization and accessing is thread safe.

**Note that this implementation is not synchronized.**

If multiple threads access a map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; merely changing the value associated with an existing key is not a structural modification.) `This is typically accomplished by synchronizing on some object that naturally encapsulates the map. If no such object exists, the map should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedSortedMap method.`

Comment: Yes it does, and yes it will.

Comment: @MikeNakis If threads just manipulate the values inside but not modifying the structure, is it thread safe in a non synchronized Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the Javadoc is rather confusing because if you modify the map at all (including when you are merely changing the value associated with an existing key), you want to synchronize all operations in almost all cases. The (almost) only time you do not need to synchronize is if the map is completely read-only after being published.

Now, why does the Javadoc say `If ... at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally` - it's because if you are merely changing the value associated with an existing key, then the worst thing that can happen is that you read stale value for some unspecified time. In contrast, if a structural change is made without synchronization, then much worse things can happen (like `NullPointerException`s, infinite loops).

It's however almost always better to synchronize or use a concurrent collection rather than allowing stale values.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it means to create a lock and move the map modification logic
>   into a synchronized block or something else all together.
>   Will only the structural modification requires synchronization and
>   accessing is thread safe.

No it is not enough.
 Synchronizing only the processing that makes a structure modification is not enough because if a method that reads the map is not synchronized, the method can be invoked concurrently with the synchronized method.
So, the access to the Map could be concurrent with a reading operation and a structure modification operation. Which is undesirable.

Finally, it means that all access to the map should be synchronized if multiple threads access the map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structure.

Comment: Not to mention that operations that only "read" the data structure might actually change them (splay trees for example). You don't know (and you shouldn't need to know) what the implementation of `get()` might do under the hood.

Comment: @biziclop  Thank your for your feedback. I find that a public reading method that performs a modification of the Map is a terrible API. Would have you an example in TreeMap  or in Java Collection please ?

Comment: As I said, that's how a splay tree genuinely works. The last element you searched for will be moved to the root of the tree to speed up subsequent lookups for the same element. The built-in `TreeMap` doesn't, but it's perfectly legitimate for an implementation to change its internal state in `get()`, as long as it doesn't affect anything visible from the outside.

Comment: Indeed for a splay tree conceptually. I agree totally that it is legitimate to do it but I think that for the sake of the concurrency concern, the API of the method should specify. For example : synchronizing a classic `HashMap` that performs only reading once accessible to the client is an expensive trade off and should be avoided.