# java: issue while access value from TreeMap in multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, treemap

I have use TreeMap to store key value.
For key using custom object.
But once I have faced very strange issue, I am not able to get value which I have set earlier(with same key).
below is my code

```
public final class TestOptions implements Cloneable {   
    private Map<StorageSystemOptionKey, Object> options = new TreeMap<StorageSystemOptionKey, Object>();
private static final class StorageSystemOptionKey implements Comparable<StorageSystemOptionKey> {
    /** Constant used to create hashcode */
    private static final int HASH = 31;

    private final Class<? extends StorageRepository> storageRepositoryClass;

    /** The option name */
    private final String name;

    private StorageSystemOptionKey(Class<? extends StorageRepository> storageRepositoryClass, String name) {
        this.storageRepositoryClass = storageRepositoryClass;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int compareTo(StorageSystemOptionKey o) {
        int ret = storageRepositoryClass.getName().compareTo(o.storageRepositoryClass.getName());
        if (ret != 0) {
            return ret;
        }
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final StorageSystemOptionKey that = (StorageSystemOptionKey) o;

        if (!storageRepositoryClass.equals(that.storageRepositoryClass)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!name.equals(that.name)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = storageRepositoryClass.hashCode();
        result = HASH * result + name.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    }

    void setOption(Class<? extends StorageRepository> fileSystemClass, String name, Object value) {
        options.put(new StorageSystemOptionKey(fileSystemClass, name), value);
    }

    Object getOption(Class<? extends StorageRepository> fileSystemClass, String name) {
        StorageSystemOptionKey key = new StorageSystemOptionKey(fileSystemClass, name);
        return options.get(key);
    }

    boolean hasOption(Class<? extends StorageRepository> fileSystemClass, String name) {
        StorageSystemOptionKey key = new StorageSystemOptionKey(fileSystemClass, name);
        return options.containsKey(key);
    }

    public int compareTo(TestOptions other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return 0;
        }

        int propsSz = options == null ? 0 : options.size();
        int propsFkSz = other.options == null ? 0 : other.options.size();
        if (propsSz < propsFkSz) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (propsSz > propsFkSz) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (propsSz == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        int hash = options.hashCode();
        int hashFk = other.options.hashCode();
        if (hash < hashFk) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (hash > hashFk) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        TestOptions clone = new TestOptions();
        clone.options = new TreeMap<StorageSystemOptionKey, Object>(options);
        return clone;
    }
}
```

calling method to set and get like

```
public abstract Class<? extends StorageRepository> getStorageRepositoryClass();


public Class<? extends StorageRepository> getStorageRepositoryClass() {
        return MyImpl.class;
}
TestOptions opt =new TestOptions(); // shared accross all Threads
Object getProperty(String name) {
    return opt.getOption(getStorageRepositoryClass(),  name);       
}
 void setProperty(String name, Object value) {
        opt.setOption(getStorageRepositoryClass(), name, value);
    }
```

Using set and get method in multi-threaded application.
queries:
I am calling set/get in multiple time then also I was not able to get value which was set earlier(same key)
Is this due to **Treeset implementation is not synchronized**
or problem with **hashCode**, **equals** or **compareTo** method implementation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741682/treemap-synchronization-documentation-explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a quick glance your `compareTo()`, `equals()` and `hashCode()` look fine. Note that `TreeMap` will mostly use `compareTo()` to find elements so that method needs to be correct (your's looks technically correct).

However, `TreeMap` and `TreeSet` (as well as other basic collections and maps) are not thread-safe and thus concurrent modifications can cause all kinds of unexpected behavior. We once had a case where 2 threads were trying to add a single element to a hashmap and the threads ended up in an endless loop because the internal list to resolve clashes produced a cycle (due to the concurrent put).

So either use the `ConcurrentXxxx` maps and collections or synchronize access to yours.

Answer (score 2):

TreeSet is not synchronized. I belive [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap-source.html) might be better.

Check also your [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--), [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals--) implementation